# python proxy request can't fetch data from www.google.com

Tags: python, proxy, socks

I use Shadowsocks to get out from the Chinese GFW. It works fine when I use chrome to browse www.google.com. 
Recently I am learning something about python crawlers, and I want to fetch data from www.google.com by using `request`.

I learned that I have to set proxy to get out from the GFW, and the code is like

```
import socket
import socks
import requests

socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 1080)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
print(requests.get('http://ifconfig.me/ip').text)
```

and then I get the address of my Shadowsocks server

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 /Users/lsongseven/PycharmProjects/wordcloud/cl.py
52.73.41.9

and here is my Shadowsocks configuration
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix1hq.png)

However, when I use this script to fetch data from google, it doesn't work anymore

```
import socket
import socks
import requests

socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 1080)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
print(requests.get('https://www.google.com/').text)
```

Here is the error message:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 /Users/lsongseven/PycharmProjects/wordcloud/cl.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 329, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 376, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 983, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 628, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:646)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:646)'),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lsongseven/PycharmProjects/wordcloud/cl.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(requests.get('https://www.google.com/').text)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 506, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:646)'),))
```

So the problem is that Shadowsocks works fine but the python script cannot work, does anyone have some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

"SSLEOFError" Seems like OpenSSL cause this prolbem.
You may try to upgrade your OpenSSL viesion,or reinstall OpenSSl.

Comment: I upgrade my OpenSSL to the version of 1.0.2l  25 May 2017, but I still cannot connect to google. Now I get this error message: ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:748)

Comment: Try using python2 instead of python3 to do the same work. I don'n konw why, but sometimes I met other odd problems, only ptyhon2 works.